# How to manually find the minors of a matrix in R programming?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am supposed to create a function that returns all the minors of a given matrix. I use a for loop to delete the necessary row/column but every time it iterates, it just writes over the previous minor. How can I keep a copy of all the minors? This is what I have so far in the function: (Suppose that b is my given matrix)

```
minors <- function(b, i, j){
  for(i in 1: nrow(b)){
    for(j in 1: ncol(b)){
      a = b[-i,-j]
    }
  }
  a
}

b = matrix(c(2,3,5,6,7,1,9,4,5), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
minors(b, i, j)
```

Any help/tips/advice will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please add a reprex

Comment: Also r is not really loop friendly you are probably going to end up not using for loops most of the time, there are more functional ways e.g https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/07/avoiding-loops-in-r-an-example-with-principal-minors/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by minors? Do you want the linear algebra one? `a[i, j] =det(b[-i,-j])`  where `a` is the matrix of your minors

Comment: just put `a <- list()` at the top of your function and change inside the loop to `a <- c(a, list(b[-i,-j]))`

Comment: I edited my code to make it reproducible. Will check the link you sent. This program is basically just to get myself more acquainted with R and matrices for the time being, without the use of too many in-built functions @Bruno

Comment: Yes, exactly the one from linear algebra @Onyambu

Comment: This worked perfectly! Can't believe it was just that simple. Thanks so much. @rawr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the minors, you could use a double for loop as shown below:

```
minors <- function(b){
  n <- nrow(b)
  a <- matrix(NA, n, n)
  for(i in 1:n)
    for(j in 1:n)
      a[i, j] = det(b[-i, -j])
    a
}
b = matrix(c(2,3,5,6,7,1,9,4,5), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
minors(b) 
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   31   -5  -32
[2,]   21  -35  -28
[3,]  -39  -19   -4

cofactors <- function(b) (-1)^(row(b)+col(b)) *minors(b)
cofactors(b)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   31    5  -32
[2,]  -21  -35   28
[3,]  -39   19   -4
```

Comment: To get them all just add `idx <- expand.grid(1:nrow(b), 1:ncol(b))` and `apply(idx, 1, function(x) minors(b, x[1], x[2]))`.

Comment: @programmingnoob What exactly is the definition of minors? Its the determinant.  *If A is a square matrix, then the minor of the entry in the i th row and j th column (also called the (i, j) minor, or a first minor[1]) is the determinant of the submatrix formed by deleting the i th row and j th column.*

Comment: @programmingnoob what you are asking for is not the minor, but rather a submatrix whose determinant will be the minor. In that case, use a list: